# laravel DB::raw count data even if is null

Tags: php, laravel, charts

I have this query:

```
$providercounter = DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(provider) as count'),'users.provider')
            ->groupBy('provider')
            ->orderBy('count','desc')
            ->get();
    foreach($providercounter as $provider){
      $name[] = $provider->provider;
      $count[] = $provider->count;
    }
    $providerUsers = Charts::create('bar', 'highcharts')
       ->title('Providers users')
       ->labels($name)
       ->values($count)
       ->responsive(true);
```

This will retrieve my users `provider` column in chart and count them.

## ISSUE

If my users are registered by their social network accounts such as `facebook, google etc.` it will get data, but **if my users are registered by email address from my website (as their `provider` column is `null`) it will not retrieve and count them**.

## Question

How can I include my users data which their provided column is null?

Comment: just... set provided to 'email'

Comment: @Tschallacka with all due respect but it was the must ridiculous idea i ever heard!    I want count them by their providers not emails!   I want to say eg. `10 users by Facebook registered` whats the connection with email?!

Comment: Well right now when someone registers by email, you don't save that it's registered by email. It seems even you haven't made provider a relation but a string field, adding a lot to database bloat. Instead of logging null I prefer logging useful information that's clear on the get go. Null is reserved for unknowns. Try always storing usefull information: provider = email, provider = csv, provider = CRM provider = twitter, etc...  Can you confirm that provider is a string field at this moment?

Comment: and what happens if you change   `$name[] = $provider->provider;` to `$name[] = $provider->provider?:'email';`

Comment: @Tschallacka my providers are coming from callback urls from social networks websites, yest they are string but is not like admin or users have ability to input them is dynamically, so if user register by email `provider` will be null else will get provider name.

Comment: @Tschallacka let me try that.

Comment: @Tschallacka I will get `email` as label without any `values` while i have users with null `provider` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IFNULL`

```
$providercounter = DB::table('users')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(provider) as count'),'users.provider')
        ->groupBy(DB::Raw('IFNULL( users.provider , 0 )'))
        ->orderBy('count','desc')
        ->get();
```

or set provider field a default value 0
and consider zero as users with no provider

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mynewsite.users.provider' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select count(provider) as count, `users`.`provider` from `users` group by IFNULL( provider , 0 ) order by `count` desc)`

Comment: you can use only by setting strict into false on config/database.php and it works.

'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'strict' => false,
    ]
]
However it's better to edit sql query than suppress it's warning.

Comment: same result still not get them `(users without provider)` in my chart.

Comment: var_dump $providercounter what is the result

Comment: Or you give a value which has no provider like zero or set provider field a default value like zero. So you will get the list of user without provider

Comment: set provider field a default value like zero.Then you don't have to worry about this

Comment: Consider zero as users without provider

Comment: can't we use some kind of if statement? like this i should edit all my registering process to add default provider for email registered users.

Comment: No you can give default value in your mysql table structure. No need to edit all rows

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your main query to :

If you want to get **`provider = null`** use this

```
$providercounter = DB::table('users')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(provider) as count'),'users.provider')
        ->whereNull('provider')
        ->groupBy('provider')
        ->orderBy('count','desc')
        ->get();
```

Or If you want to get **`provider != null`** use this

```
$providercounter = DB::table('users')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(provider) as count'),'users.provider')
        ->whereNotNull('provider')
        ->groupBy('provider')
        ->orderBy('count','desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: i want get both, null or not get and count it.

Comment: @WalterCejas honestly i don't even remember what project this question was about after all these times :) sorry man :(